# C++ file input, stream, and compile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, iostream

So the problem is that I'm getting error C3867 when I'm attempting to close the file stream (at least that's what I hope I'm doing). The intent is to make a program that uses an input file to read in the values into an array and from there determine what the highest and lowest numbers of the array are. The arraySize can be less or more than 10 data items, and we must check the file for open errors before reading data from the file and to close the file after finished reading the elements into the array. This I can do later but it's an instruction anyway.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int arraySize = 10;
    float numbers[arraySize];
    int count = 0;
    string fileName;
    float high, low;

    fstream inputFile(fileName, ios::in);

    cout << "What is the filename you wish to use? ";
    cin >> fileName;

    inputFile.open(fileName);
    while (count < arraySize && inputFile >> numbers[count])
        count++;
    inputFile.close;

    high = numbers[0];
    low = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        if (numbers[i] > high)
            high = numbers[i];
        if (numbers[i] < low)
            low = numbers[i];
    }

    cout << "The highest number in the file is: " << high;
    cout << "The lowest number in the file is: " << low;

    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What is the exact error (and where exactly are you trying to close the file)?

Comment: Someone below gave the correct thing. Apparantly I was an idiot and didn't have a parentheses at the end of input.close(). Which is odd as VS2013 didn't give that as a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `inputFile.close()` as a function with the parentheses.

Comment: Or not call it at all as it will be automatically closed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @user3147771 Yes, I see now.

Comment: The program is fine either with `inputFile.close()`, or omitting the line entirely. However it is interesting to see why exactly `inputFile.close;` gets an error. The MSDN docs for [Error C3867](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf.aspx) appears to correspond to the code `&inputFile.close;` . G++ 4.8.2 gives a similar error for `&inputFile.close;`. However, `inputFile.close;` is different: it does not have the `&` operator, and C++11 [conv.func] specifically says that the name of a non-static member function does NOT decay to a pointer, so I am not sure what should happen!

Comment: g++ gives a bogus error about function overloading, however `std::fstream::close()` does not have any overloads.